# Centering variable number of divs in container

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a Bootstrap container containing 4 internal divs centered on a page (these are rendered dynamically in my actual web application).  In certain instances, I only render 3 internal divs, but when I remove 1 of the paragraphs, the remaining content in the container floats to the left (due to the float tag in the css).  How can I center 3 paragraphs rather than having them float left?

```
<div class="expertise_section text-center">
<div class="row">
<div class="container">
<h2>Centered Headline</h2>
<div class="expertise_section_inner row">
</div>

<!-- ***** if the below is removed, the remaining 3 divs do not center correctly -->
<div class="expertise_div blue_div" >
<div class="expertise_content">
<p>Paragraph 1...</p>
</div>
<a href="https://www.jsfiddle.net" target="_blank">READ MORE</a></div>

<div class="expertise_div green_div" >
<div class="expertise_content">
<p>Paragraph 2...</p>
</div>
<a href="https://www.jsfiddle.net" target="_blank">READ MORE</a></div>

<div class="expertise_div maroon_div">
<div class="expertise_content">
<p>Paragraph 3...</p>
</div>
<a href="https://www.jsfiddle.net" target="_blank">READ MORE</a></div>

<div class="expertise_div orange_div">
<div class="expertise_content">
<p>Paragraph 4...</p>
</div>
<a href="https://www.jsfiddle.net" target="_blank">READ MORE</a></div>

</div>
</div>
</div>
```

The CSS is below:

```
@charset "utf-8";

.expertise_section {
    padding: 85px 0;
}
.expertise_section h2 {
    font-weight:500;
    margin-top:7px;
}
.expertise_div {  
  float: left;
    width: 24.2%;
    margin-right:1.05%;
}
.expertise_div:nth-child(4n+4) {
    margin-right:0px;
}
.expertise_div p {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    color: #6c6c6c;
    font-weight: 300;
}
.expertise_content {
    border-bottom: 2px solid #45acba;
    border-top: 2px solid #45acba;
    margin: 18px 0;
    padding: 26px 0;
}
.expertise_content p:last-child {
    margin-bottom:2px;
}
.expertise_div a {
  color: #3a9cab;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 500;
}
.expertise_section_inner {
    margin-top:36px;
}
.green_div .expertise_content {
    border-color:#8ebb29;
}
.green_div a {
    color:#8ebb29;
}
.maroon_div .expertise_content {
    border-color:#81515d;
}
.maroon_div a {
    color:#81515d;
}
.orange_div .expertise_content {
    border-color:#d86435;
}
.orange_div a {
    color:#d86435;
}
.show_1023 {
    display:none;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1199px) {
    .container {
        padding:0px 35px !important;
    }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 1023px) {
    .expertise_div {
        float: left;
        margin-right: 3.2%;
        width: 48%;
        margin-bottom:53px;
    }
    .expertise_div:nth-child(2n+2) {
        margin-right: 0;
    }
    .expertise_section {
        padding: 85px 0 30px;
    }
    .expertise_section_inner {
        padding: 0 101px;
    }
    header {
        padding: 20px 15px;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 951px) {
  .container {
        padding: 0 30px !important;
    text-align: center;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    .container {
        padding: 0 30px !important;
    text-align: center;
    }
    .expertise_section {
        padding: 78px 0 45px;
    }
    .expertise_div {
        width:100%;
        margin-right:0px;
        margin-bottom:31px;
    }
    .expertise_section_inner {
        padding: 0;
        margin-top:33px;
    }
    .hide_767 {
        display:none;
    }
    .show_767 {
        display:block;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 479px) {
    .container {
        padding: 0 30px !important;
    text-align: center;
    }
    .hide_480 {
        display:none !important;
    }
    .show_479 {
        display:block !important;
    }
}
```

A jsfiddle is here: https://jsfiddle.net/PaulPerkins/4zh6k6oL/2/

Comment: Not sure if this is a possibility for your project, but if you switch to the new Bootstrap v4 you can take advantage of the flexbox-based column classes. This should do what you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add

```
.container {
    text-align: center;
}
```

and remove `float: left;` everywhere. Instead make `div`-s behave like inline elements with `display: inline-block;` for `.expertise_div` - they will always be centered being inline elements of `.container`. Also you have to refine your styles concerning the elements' margins for every viewport size taking into account the variable number of elements. The [Flex Box Layout](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) might be an alternative if don't want to worry about all these margins and cases.

```css
@charset "utf-8";
.container {
   text-align: center;
}
.expertise_section {
    padding: 85px 0;
}
.expertise_section h2 {
    font-weight:500;
    margin-top:7px;
}
.expertise_div {  
    display: inline-block;
    width: 24.2%;
    margin-right:1.05%;
}
.expertise_div:nth-child(4n+4) {
    margin-right:0px;
}
.expertise_div p {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    color: #6c6c6c;
    font-weight: 300;
}
.expertise_content {
    border-bottom: 2px solid #45acba;
    border-top: 2px solid #45acba;
    margin: 18px 0;
    padding: 26px 0;
}
.expertise_content p:last-child {
    margin-bottom:2px;
}
.expertise_div a {
  color: #3a9cab;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 500;
}
.expertise_section_inner {
    margin-top:36px;
}
.green_div .expertise_content {
    border-color:#8ebb29;
}
.green_div a {
    color:#8ebb29;
}
.maroon_div .expertise_content {
    border-color:#81515d;
}
.maroon_div a {
    color:#81515d;
}
.orange_div .expertise_content {
    border-color:#d86435;
}
.orange_div a {
    color:#d86435;
}
.show_1023 {
    display:none;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1199px) {
    .container {
        padding:0px 35px !important;
    }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 1023px) {
    .expertise_div {
        margin-right: 3.2%;
        width: 48%;
        margin-bottom:53px;
    }
    .expertise_div:nth-child(2n+2) {
        margin-right: 0;
    }
    .expertise_section {
        padding: 85px 0 30px;
    }
    .expertise_section_inner {
        padding: 0 101px;
    }
    header {
        padding: 20px 15px;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 951px) {
  .container {
        padding: 0 30px !important;
    text-align: center;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    .container {
        padding: 0 30px !important;
    text-align: center;
    }
    .expertise_section {
        padding: 78px 0 45px;
    }
    .expertise_div {
        width:100%;
        margin-right:0px;
        margin-bottom:31px;
    }
    .expertise_section_inner {
        padding: 0;
        margin-top:33px;
    }
    .hide_767 {
        display:none;
    }
    .show_767 {
        display:block;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 479px) {
    .container {
        padding: 0 30px !important;
    text-align: center;
    }
    .hide_480 {
        display:none !important;
    }
    .show_479 {
        display:block !important;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="expertise_section text-center">
<div class="row">
<div class="container">
<h2>Centered Headline</h2>
<div class="expertise_section_inner row">
</div>

<!-- ***** if the below is removed, the remaining 3 divs do not center correctly -->
<div class="expertise_div blue_div" >
<div class="expertise_content">
<p>Paragraph 1...</p>
</div>
<a href="https://www.jsfiddle.net" target="_blank">READ MORE</a></div>

<div class="expertise_div green_div" >
<div class="expertise_content">
<p>Paragraph 2...</p>
</div>
<a href="https://www.jsfiddle.net" target="_blank">READ MORE</a></div>

<div class="expertise_div maroon_div">
<div class="expertise_content">
<p>Paragraph 3...</p>
</div>
<a href="https://www.jsfiddle.net" target="_blank">READ MORE</a></div>



</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't center elements that have *float: left* property.

What you can do is render your elements as *inline-block* and use *text-align: center* on your wrapper.

Follow this fiddle:

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="boxes">
    <div class="box">
    </div>
    <div class="box">
    </div>
    <div class="box">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrapper{
  width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-size: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

.boxes{
  width: 100%:
}

.box{
  font-size: 0;
  width: 250px;
  height: 150px;
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nftxsw7h/